# Kendo UI - Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, kendo-ui, telerik

So in my view file a have a list of entries and my goal is to navigate to a screen which shows details about those entries when you click on them. This is the code for the listview:

```
<ul id="mainListView" data-role="listview" data-style="inset" 
    data-click="app.viewModels.dataViewModel.navigateToEntry">
</ul>
```

And this is the method it points to in the viewModel:

```
navigateToEntry: function(e) {
  app.mobileApp.navigate("#views/entryView.html?entno=" + e.dataItem.entno);
}
```

**The problem is** that the first time I click on it I get this:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'entno' of undefined"

The 2nd, 3rd and so on time it's working fine, but the 1st one is always throwing this error. Any ideas how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: It's hard to tell what dosn't work. I've tried to reproduce this error, but everything works correctly in my simple snipped: http://dojo.telerik.com/oNUja. Can you reproduce this error there?

Comment: Hi Jaroslaw, thanks for your input. After some more digging I think for some reason the function is being called 2 times:

`Object {target: P.fn.init[1], item: P.fn.init[1], dataItem: undefined, button: undefined, sender: b.e…d.init…}
Object {target: P.fn.init[1], item: P.fn.init[1], dataItem: m…l.k…o.d…a.M…l.d…e.init, button: undefined, sender: b.e…d.init…}`

This is the output from the console when I added `console.log(e)` in the navigateToEntry function.

Comment: Or it returns 2 objects, I'm quite new to Kendo so not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check this code:

```
navigateToEntry: function(e) {
    if(e.dataItem !== undefined){
        app.mobileApp.navigate("#views/entryView.html?entno=" + e.dataItem.entno);
    }
}
```

Does now first click work or does it not do anything?